# meaning of "do" as a substitute verb

Tags: meaning

> "In such situations it is good if you can find a mentor who can guide
>   you appropriately, but when this is not possible even self-coaching
>   will ***do***."

Is it OK to write the above sentence like this?

> "In such situations it is good if you can find a mentor who can guide
>   you appropriately, but when this is not possible even self-coaching
>   will ***be good***.

Answer (score 1):

"**X will do**" means "X is sufficient." The phrase can be used to imply that something is merely satisfactory.

> A: Do you have a knife?
>
> B: No, but I have this sharp stick.
>
> A: That will do.

It is also commonly used as understatement to describe something that is quite good.

> A: Could you pass me that sharp stick?
>
> B: How about this knife instead?
>
> A: That will do.

Note that the phrase is very often spoken as a contraction, like "that'll do."

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the first sentence is saying that a mentor would be the ideal situation, but if such an arrangement is not possible, self-coaching is a suitable alternative.  That's to say that having a mentor would be better and self-coaching is a lesser option. Both are fine, but the implication stands that self-coaching is a less ideal situation.